# Computed property from inner scope is needed in outer scope

Tags: angularjs

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0ngtz8j/

I have an outer controller: OuterCtrl. Property "Name" is in scope of OuterCtrl.

Within scope of OuterCtrl, I have inner controller: InnerCtrl. Property "Suffix" is in scope of InnerCtrl.

I need a computed property FullName (= Name + Suffix) in both the outer and inner controllers. In above given jsfiddle, I am able to get FullName in InnerCtrl. How will I make it available in OuterCtrl?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Name">
        <br>
        (Outer) Name : <strong>{{Name}}</strong>
        <br>
        (Outer) Full Name: {{FullName}}    
        <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
            Suffix: <input type="text" ng-model="Suffix">
            <br>
            (Inner) Name: {{Name}}
            <br>
            (Inner) Full Name: {{FullName}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('OuterCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Name = "Adam";

});

myApp.controller('InnerCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Suffix = "Jr.";
    $scope.FullName = $scope.Name + " " + $scope.Suffix;
    $scope.$watch('Name + Suffix', function() {
       $scope.FullName = $scope.Name +' '+$scope.Suffix;
    });
});
```

This is a simplified question for an enhancement to a complex app that I am working.  Name property has to stay in OuterCtrl. Suffix has to stay in InnerCtrl. FullName is a new functionality I need to add that I can fit anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve that is put all your model within an object, so it will be shared by the parent and child controllers.

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/83stdLy4/1/

Basically all the logic is in the main controller, but it could also be in th child one.

```
myApp.controller('OuterCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dude = {};
  $scope.dude.Name = "Adam";
  $scope.dude.Suffix = "Jr.";

  $scope.$watch('dude.Name + dude.Suffix', function () {
    $scope.dude.FullName = $scope.dude.Name + ' ' + $scope.dude.Suffix;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. But this question is simplified version of a business app that I am working. So is there a solution by adding new code by maintaining Name in OuterCtrl and Suffix in InnerCtrl? FullName is a new functionality that I can keep anywhere.. may be in a shared factory. Can you pls give pointers on how to solve this.

Comment: @Ferny yeah you could have all the logic in the child controller that deals with suffix and all, as long as it edits `$scope.dude.something` instead of directly `$scope.something`, the changes will be accessible also from the parent controller.

Comment: @Ferny check the updated jsfiddle and let me know if that answers your question http://jsfiddle.net/83stdLy4/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot floribon. I think this will work for me. I will try this tomorrow morning in office (I'm in EST). The business code is not accessible for me now to try out :(